# test_database() does not use the database given

Tags: python-2.7, flask, peewee

I'm trying to test my models using peewee's `test_database` which is supposed to use the database passed when executing the SQL in the context block. However running the test, I noticed that the production database is always used, which should not be the case.

Here's the exception I get:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_Admin (__main__.DatabaseTestSuite)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db/db_test.py", line 14, in test_Admin
    with test_database(test_db, (Admin), create_tables=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/playhouse/test_utils.py", line 21, in __enter__
    for m in self.models:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 4723, in __iter__
    return iter(self.select())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3149, in __iter__
    return iter(self.execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3142, in execute
    self._qr = ResultWrapper(model_class, self._execute(), query_meta)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 2826, in _execute
    return self.database.execute_sql(sql, params, self.require_commit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3683, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3507, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_args), traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/peewee.py", line 3676, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 835, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1019, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1302, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 981, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 393, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
ProgrammingError: (1146, u"Table 'db.admin' doesn't exist")

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the test code:

```
from db import *
import unittest
from playhouse.test_utils import test_database


test_db = MySQLDatabase('testdb', 
    user='testuser', 
    password='testpass')


class DatabaseTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_Admin(self):
        with test_database(test_db, (Admin), create_tables=True):

            Admin.create(username="testuser", 
                email="testuser@email.com")

            result = Admin.select().where(Admin.user == "testuser")

            unittest.assertIsNotNone(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I've opened an issue on the github page, but received no help so far. You can find the issue [here](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/1059). It should provide extra details if needed. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model tuple has a single item and thus requires a trailing comma. Changing this

```
with test_database(test_db, (Admin), create_tables=True):
```

to this

```
with test_database(test_db, (Admin,), create_tables=True):
```

resolved it.